# Extending a jQuery plug-in's options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, javascript-framework

Let's say I have a JavaScript file named `common.js` and another named `specific.js`. In `common.js` I have the following:

```
$(".datePicker").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true
});
```

**I want to extend the options** to the DatePicker plugin to in `specific.js` by adding an `onSelect` option.

How can this be done? By adding the following?

```
$(".datePicker").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this syntax (common in jQuery plugins):

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "option-name", 'option-value' );
```